# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. in javascript and extension live server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I was just writing some JS code from a course in vs code and ran into this problem suddenly after trying to console.log()

```
const manav = [
    'Manav',
    'Aggarwal',
    2037 - 2005,
    'None',
    ['Yash', 'Uday', 'Nikhil'],
    true
];

// 0, 1, ..... 4
// 4, 3, ..... 0

for(let i = manav.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(i, manav[i]);
}

for(let exercise = 1; exercise < 4; exercise++){
    console.log(`------------ Starting exercise ${exercise}`);

    for (let rep = 1; rep < 6; rep++){
        console.log(`Lifting weight repetition ${rep} ️`);
    }
}
}
```

[image: error message]

I think the problelm is in nested for loop or live server extension

[This is what i was expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIAhI.png)

Comment: Very often this warning will actually come from one of the extensions installed in your web browser, not from any of your code. Update your screenshot to include the right hand side of the message as well, because it says there where the Warning is coming from.

Comment: actually now the code is running fine by itself and there is no problem but i did't do anything it is kinda surprising